# Getting 503 Service Unavailable Error when trying to consume Rest Service from Java code | Working fine when doing from postman

Tags: java, rest, api

I am trying to consume a rest call from java code, but getting 503-service unavailable(tried with multiple endpoints). The same is working fine when being hit via Postman/browser
No success till now

I am providing logs below
Logs:

```
**"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin\java.exe" -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:51005,suspend=y,server=n -javaagent:C:\Users\ahmedkavish.rizvi\.IdeaIC2019.1\system\captureAgent\debugger-agent.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\ahmedkavish.rizvi\Documents\ProjectWorkspace\Java\createproxyapigee\target\classes;C:\Users\ahmedkavish.rizvi\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.1.4.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-web-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ahmedkavish.rizvi\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.1.4.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ahmedkavish.rizvi\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.1.4.RELEASE\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ahmedkavish.rizvi\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.1.4.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ahmedkavish.rizvi\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.3\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\ahmedkavish.rizvi\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.3\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\ahmedkavish.rizvi\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.11.2\log4j-to-slf4j-2.11.2.jar;C:\Users\ahmedkavish.rizvi\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.11.2\log4j-api-2.11.2.jar;C:\Users\ahmedkavish.rizvi\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.26\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.26.jar;C:\Users\ahmedkavish.rizvi\.m2\repository\javax\annotation\javax.annotation-api\1.3.2\javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar;C:\Users\ahmedkavish.rizvi\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.23\snakeyaml-1.23.jar;C:\Users\ahmedkavish.rizvi\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.1.4.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-json-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ahmedkavish.rizvi\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.9.8\jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar;C:\Users\ahmedkavish.rizvi\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.9.0\jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\ahmedkavish.rizvi\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.9.8\jackson-core-2.9.8.jar;C:\Users\ahmedkavish.rizvi\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.9.8\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.8.jar;C:\Users\ahmedkavish.rizvi\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.9.8\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.8.jar;C:\Users\ahmedkavish.rizvi\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.9.8\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.9.8.jar;C:\Users\ahmedkavish.rizvi\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.1.4.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ahmedkavish.rizvi\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.17\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar;C:\Users\ahmedkavish.rizvi\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\9.0.17\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.17.jar;C:\Users\ahmedkavish.rizvi\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\9.0.17\tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.17.jar;C:\Users\ahmedkavish.rizvi\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\validator\hibernate-validator\6.0.16.Final\hibernate-validator-6.0.16.Final.jar;C:\Users\ahmedkavish.rizvi\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\2.0.1.Final\validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\ahmedkavish.rizvi\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.3.2.Final\jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\ahmedkavish.rizvi\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.4.0\classmate-1.4.0.jar;C:\Users\ahmedkavish.rizvi\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.1.6.RELEASE\spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ahmedkavish.rizvi\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.1.6.RELEASE\spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ahmedkavish.rizvi\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.1.6.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ahmedkavish.rizvi\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.1.6.RELEASE\spring-aop-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ahmedkavish.rizvi\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.1.6.RELEASE\spring-expression-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ahmedkavish.rizvi\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.26\slf4j-api-1.7.26.jar;C:\Users\ahmedkavish.rizvi\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.1.6.RELEASE\spring-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ahmedkavish.rizvi\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.1.6.RELEASE\spring-jcl-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ahmedkavish.rizvi\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.1.4.RELEASE\spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ahmedkavish.rizvi\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.1.6.RELEASE\spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ahmedkavish.rizvi\.m2\repository\net\minidev\json-smart\2.3\json-smart-2.3.jar;C:\Users\ahmedkavish.rizvi\.m2\repository\net\minidev\accessors-smart\1.2\accessors-smart-1.2.jar;C:\Users\ahmedkavish.rizvi\.m2\repository\org\ow2\asm\asm\5.0.4\asm-5.0.4.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1\lib\idea_rt.jar" createApiWithCurl.Application
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:51005', transport: 'socket'
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.4.RELEASE)
2019-04-19 15:08:31.628  INFO 7740 --- [           main] createApiWithCurl.Application            : Starting Application on WKSBAN22APP1300 with PID 7740 (C:\Users\ahmedkavish.rizvi\Documents\ProjectWorkspace\Java\createproxyapigee\target\classes started by ahmedkavish.rizvi in C:\Users\ahmedkavish.rizvi\Documents\ProjectWorkspace\Java\createproxyapigee)
2019-04-19 15:08:31.644  INFO 7740 --- [           main] createApiWithCurl.Application            : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-04-19 15:08:33.343  INFO 7740 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-04-19 15:08:33.374  INFO 7740 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-04-19 15:08:33.374  INFO 7740 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.17]
2019-04-19 15:08:33.538  INFO 7740 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-04-19 15:08:33.538  INFO 7740 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1725 ms
2019-04-19 15:08:33.798  INFO 7740 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-04-19 15:08:34.124  INFO 7740 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2019-04-19 15:08:34.124  INFO 7740 --- [           main] createApiWithCurl.Application            : Started Application in 3.081 seconds (JVM running for 3.906)
2019-04-19 15:08:41.200  INFO 7740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-04-19 15:08:41.200  INFO 7740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-04-19 15:08:41.209  INFO 7740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 9 ms
2019-04-19 15:10:13.273 ERROR 7740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException$ServiceUnavailable: 503 Service Unavailable] with root cause
org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException$ServiceUnavailable: 503 Service Unavailable
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException.create(HttpServerErrorException.java:85) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:124) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:778) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:736) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:670) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:579) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at createApiWithCurl.broker.ServiceBroker.getApisList(ServiceBroker.java:39) ~[classes/:na]
    at createApiWithCurl.business.ApiBusiness.getApisList(ApiBusiness.java:22) ~[classes/:na]
    at createApiWithCurl.controller.ApiController.getApisList(ApiController.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_202]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_202]
2019-04-19 15:13:21.032 ERROR 7740 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException$ServiceUnavailable: 503 Service Unavailable] with root cause
org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException$ServiceUnavailable: 503 Service Unavailable
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException.create(HttpServerErrorException.java:85) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:124) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:778) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:736) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:670) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:579) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at createApiWithCurl.broker.ServiceBroker.getApisList(ServiceBroker.java:39) ~[classes/:na]
    at createApiWithCurl.business.ApiBusiness.getApisList(ApiBusiness.java:22) ~[classes/:na]
    at createApiWithCurl.controller.ApiController.getApisList(ApiController.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_202]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_202]**
```

Please find below the broker class code which i am using to cosnume the rest call

Code:

```
package createApiWithCurl.broker;

import createApiWithCurl.model.FacadeResponse;
import org.springframework.http.*;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ServiceBroker {

    private String baseUrl = "http://httpbin.org/get";
    private String resourceUrl = "/apis";

    public FacadeResponse getApisList(String orgName) throws IOException {

        HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        /** set up HTTP Basic Authentication Header **/
        requestHeaders.add("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        /**Request entity is created with request headers**/
        HttpEntity<Object> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(requestHeaders);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        /**Rest Call to consume Rest Service**/
        ResponseEntity<FacadeResponse> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(baseUrl,HttpMethod.GET,requestEntity,FacadeResponse.class);

        FacadeResponse facadeResponse = responseEntity.getBody();
        return facadeResponse;

    }
}
```

Comment: Solved
Use : 
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "<Proxy host>");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "<proxy port>");

Comment: Thank you so so much. 
1. Why it is required in Springboot app, not in postmane?
2. I think it is better to pass through VM argument, instead of setting it in application, 
-Dhttp.proxyHost=X.X.X.X

Comment: and write the solution also, other than comment. It's a valid question. I came searching for this